# Popular question badge inevitability

Tags: discussion, badges, popular-question

Consider the "popular question" badge:  "Asked a question with 1,000 views".  Would I be correct in expecting that every question will eventually receive this badge as web crawlers look through the pages?

Comment: I always thought that badge was a bit weak; it has 56000 recipients, or almost twice as many as the insanely trivial Autobiographer. It's pretty much just "old question"; popularity has little to do with it since time isn't factored in

Answer (score 2):

Not if they're excluded from the counting. But if you can convince a thousand geeks to [archive binge](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArchiveBinge) the trilogy, perhaps!

Comment: If people could mark a question as read, they'd be more likely to archive binge their favorite tag. +1 for linking to tv tropes.